# zfs convert linear to raidz5 or rebuild

Tags: zfs, raid5, raidz

Can i convert my linear span to a raidz-5?  I finally have enough hard drives, and dont really want to thrash them about refilling with the backup data that they need to be holding.

so currently, the command i built is not raid, but uses linear span

```
    $ zpool status
      pool: san
     state: ONLINE
    status: Some supported features are not enabled on the pool. The pool can
            still be used, but some features are unavailable.
    action: Enable all features using 'zpool upgrade'. Once this is done,
            the pool may no longer be accessible by software that does not support
            the features. See zpool-features(5) for details.
      scan: scrub repaired 0 in 7h28m with 0 errors on Sat Apr  2 02:58:32 2016
    config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        san         ONLINE       0     0     0
          sdd       ONLINE       0     0     0
          sdc       ONLINE       0     0     0
          sde       ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

can i add another 2tb, convert all theses into the raidz5 straight across, so my checksum and crc will all become worthwhile, without erasing my data?

```
$ zfs list
NAME                                USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
san                                4.91T   371G  2.85M  /san

$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
`-sda1   8:1    0   1.8T  0 part
sdb      8:16   0 232.9G  0 disk
|-sdb1   8:17   0  1007K  0 part
|-sdb2   8:18   0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
|-sdb3   8:19   0    20G  0 part /
|-sdb4   8:20   0 208.9G  0 part /home
`-sdb5   8:21   0   3.1M  0 part
sdc      8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk
|-sdc1   8:33   0   1.8T  0 part
`-sdc9   8:41   0     8M  0 part
sdd      8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk
|-sdd1   8:49   0   1.8T  0 part
`-sdd9   8:57   0     8M  0 part
sde      8:64   0   1.8T  0 disk
|-sde1   8:65   0   1.8T  0 part
`-sde9   8:73   0     8M  0 part
```

sda is the new guy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do anything with what you have other than adding drives to mirror the existing set (you'd need three) or rebuild with the ZFS protection level that makes the most sense for you.